# PyTest parameterised test with csv data

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

In many PyTest scripts example with parameterised data such as

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input1, input2, output", [(5, 5, 10), (7, 5, 12)])
def test_add(input1, input2, output):
    assert input1 + input2 == output, "failed"
```

annotation. However, there is a requirement for me to fetch cvs/xlsx data in PyTest parameterise for multiple `test_` methods.

Lets say I have table in CSV as

| input1 | input2 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 7 | 5 | 12 |

Can anyone suggest the detailed solution for reading the data from CSV and use it in above test method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `pytest-csv-params` which you can install using `pip install pytest-csv-params`

Then you could import data from your csv as shown below

```
from pytest_csv_params.decorator import csv_params

@csv_params(
    data_file="/path to csv/addition.csv",
    data_casts={
        "input1": int,
        "input2": int,
        "output": int,
    },
)
def test_addition(input1, input2, output):
    assert input1+ input2 == output, "failed"
```

More information could be found here [link](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-csv-params/)

Comment: This is good resource. Is it possible to mention the sheet name from where this data to be fetched. Also, what about dynamic data from CSV where the titles and values may differ time to time?